# Uncertainty for measuring a resistor

Tags: current-measurement, measurement, voltage-measurement

I am trying to calculate the uncertainty of a measure on a resistor. The expected value of the resistor is 45 mΩ. For measuring the resistor I used the two following instruments:

- [SM500-CP-90](https://www.delta-elektronika.nl/sites/default/files/2023-06/SM15K_DTS_V202306_0.pdf)
- [Agilent 34401A](https://www.keysight.com/us/en/assets/7018-06774/data-sheets/5968-0162.pdf)

The current passing through the resistor is 15 A. The uncertainty of the current seems to be 8 mA according to the datasheet:

[image]

The uncertainty of the voltage is the following according to the datasheet:

[image]

The value of the measurement is 604 mV. So the uncertainty for the voltage is:

$$\frac{0.004}{100}\cdot 604\ \mathrm{mV}+\frac{0.0007}{100}\cdot 1000\ \mathrm{mV} = 0.031\ \mathrm{mV} $$

The uncertainty for the current is 8 mA.

So the uncertainty of the resistor can be calcultated as follows:

$$\frac{604\ \mathrm{mV} + 0.031}{15-0.008} = 40.290\ \mathrm{m\Omega} $$
$$\frac{604\ \mathrm{mV} - 0.031}{15+0.008} = 40.243\ \mathrm{m\Omega} $$

$$\frac{40.290-40.243}{2} = 0.024\ \mathrm{m\Omega} $$

It seems to me to be a very low uncertainty. Do you think that I have made an error ?

Comment: 8mA is the load regulation, which is not related directly to the accuracy of the current. The accuracy of the reading is specified in the datasheet, so if you are reading the actual current then the regulation is not important. But the accuracy of the reading is important.

Comment: Ok i see what you mean. Thank you !